# Media element source not changing in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to build a media player in WPF. There is a Media player and a few buttons. The source for the player is initially set to a particular video. Clicking on each  of the buttons need to change the source of the media player to different URI. 
The first video play correctly, however the button clicks don't seem to change the source of the media player. I checked possible solutions and SO, but I don't seem to notice anything different. I might have missed some basic somewhere as I am new to WPF.

My code is below:

```
<MediaElement Source="C:\video\a.mpg" Name="myMediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="208" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="252" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill"      MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"/>
```

This is how initialized the media element

And this is how I am trying to change the source :

```
  private void ChangeMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Media to be changed");// This is called and a message box pops up showing this message.
     myMediaElement.Source = new System.Uri("C:\video\b.mpg");
     MessageBox.Show("Media changed successfully"); // never gets called and message box does not pop up 
  }
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried what d.moncada said, my application began to crash. I attached my debugger and figured out that it crashed where the path was being set.

```
   myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:\video\a.mpg", UriKind.Absolute); //It crashed here
```

this was the error message :

```
Additional information: Invalid URI: A Dos path must be rooted, for example, 'c:/'.
```

I search a lot on Google, but nothing seemed to solve my problem. Then I thought if there could be any issue with escape sequence etc. 
I just tried  double slashes instead of single slashes in the path and it worked like magic!

```
 myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("C:\\video\\a.mpg", UriKind.Absolute); //It worked!!
```

I don't know the  exact reason behind this, but it did solve my problem.

Comment: ahh that's right, you can also use @ as well. Im going to update my answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hard-coded source inside the XAML, and specify that the path is absolute when you create the URI

xaml:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="208" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="252" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Fill" MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"/>
```

code-behind:

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"C:\video\a.mpg", UriKind.Absolute);
}

private void ChangeMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Media to be changed");// This is called and a message box pops up showing this message.
    myMediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"C:\video\b.mpg", UriKind.Absolute);
    MessageBox.Show("Media changed successfully"); // never gets called and message box does not pop up 
}
```

Also note that the paths need to have the backslash escaped correctly. You can either use `@` on the entire string, or `\\` for each slash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @d.mocada. I tried your solution, but  it didn't work for me. But it did help me to achieve what I wanted. 
There was some issue with the path. I will post my solution below along with an explanation of how your solution helped me achieve it.